# Mysql Dump in shell script, automatically read DB variables from settings.php

Tags: mysql, shell

I am writing a script that will automatically back up about 70 websites, each with different DB variables.

What I am trying to figure out is how to read the DB variables.  They are stored in each site's settings.php, so it seems like reading from there would be the way to go.  How can I go about reading those from settings.php?

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE : Since you have not included any of your code or what you have
>   tried. I will try to give you good suggestion.

Since your having 70 different websites, hope they may be having the **settings.php** file in different folder or something.

I would like to suggest you to make a **setting_include.php** file at every root folder of project and in that have the following

### setting_include.php

$setting_path = 'your path to settings as it may vary project to project';

Now think that your **settings.php** has the following settings

### settings.php

```
$database['mysql_username']           = 'username';
$database['mysql_database_name']      = 'database_name';
$database['mysql_database_password']  = 'database_password';
$database['mysql_port']               = 'port';
```

I am assuming that for backup you may loop into every all the projects. I dont know how your doing.

```
$errors = array();
foreach($projects as $project){
    /* Check whether the file exists or not */
    include_once $project.'/setting_include.php';
    if(file_exists($setting_path)){
        include_once $setting_path;
        /* Once you include your settings.php you will be able to access it as follows */
        echo $database['mysql_database_name'];
        echo $database['mysql_database_password'];

        /* Her you can write your script to take a back up */
    }else{
        $errors[] = $project.' : path was not loaded properly';
    }

}
```